# Как с помощью ServiceWorker производить route (роутинг)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

## Как с помощью ServiceWorker производить роутинг импортируемых библиотек/скриптов

### хочу - конечная цель

хочу менять

это (someFile.js)

```
import('react')
import 'react'
import * as React 'react'
```

на это (обработка/роутинг - результат работы)

```
// например
import('https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js')
```

### что имею

#### sw.js

```
/// <reference lib="DOM" />
/// <reference lib="WebWorker" />
const log = (...q) => console.log('sw:', ...q)

/** @type { Array<(self:ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) => void> } */
const fs = [];

test: {
    fs.push(self => {
        self.addEventListener('install', e => { log('install', e) })
        self.addEventListener('activate', e => { log('activate', e) })
        self.addEventListener('fetch', e => { log('fetch', e) })
    })
}
fetch: {
    fs.push(self => {
        self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
            const { request } = e
            const { url } = request
            log('fetch', `url: ${url}`)
        })
    })
}
cacheAddRequests: {
    const cacheAddRequests = async () => {
        try {
            /**@type {(string | Request)[]} */
            const requests = [
                self.origin
            ]
            log({ requests })
            const cache = await caches.open('v1')
            await cache.addAll(requests)
        }
        catch (e) { console.warn(e) }
    }
    fs.push(self => {
        self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(cacheAddRequests()))
    })
}

INIT: {
    fs.forEach(f => f(self))
}
```

#### index.html

```
<body>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
                .then((reg) => {
                    // регистрация сработала
                    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope)
                    console.log({ reg })
                }).catch((error) => {
                    // регистрация прошла неудачно
                    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error)
                })
        }
    </script>
    <!-- <script src="index.js" type="module"></script> -->
    <script type="module">
        // fetch('/index.js')
        // fetch('index.js')
        // -,-
        // import('/index.js')
        // import('index.js')
        // -,-
        import '/index.js'
        // import 'index.js'
    </script>
</body>
```

### ВОПРОС

оно как бы работает, но:

- может велосипед уже изобрели (см. конечная цель)
- прошу взгляд со стороны
- оно как бы работает, но:

  ```
  <script type="module">
      // fetch('/index.js')  // работает
      // fetch('index.js')   // работает
      // -,-
      // import('/index.js') // работает
      // import('index.js')  // нет // Err
      // -,-
      import '/index.js'     // работает
      // import 'index.js'   // нет // Err
  </script>
  <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>  // работает
  ```

  под работает я понимаю что срабатывает `` log('fetch', `url: ${url}`) `` в блоке `fetch`

Comment: говоря проще - хочу https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths для ES6 модулей

Comment: Для чего это все нужно? Почему не берете webpack, rollup или иной сборщик? (Просто любопытство)

Comment: Просто любопытство :). С тем же успехом можно использовать уже упомянутый requirejs. У нас есть стандарт(пять лет как уже, скоро в школу пора), у нас есть импорт ... новомодные PWA и worker's.

Comment: а ещё есть такая штука как CDN, например https://unpkg.com/ да, у них есть флаг `?module` но если бы его не было, то мой "вопрос" имел бы вполне практическое применение

Comment: а так, нууу, можно подгружать шрифты из CDN а если CDN слёг - брать их локально, например

Comment: @Ghost, если любопытно - возьмите код из вопроса да поиграйте, ответ можно оформить с указанием что (разработчики браузеров решили что локальный импорт должен начинаться с `/` `./` `../`, и всё тут, вот так.), а так код-то рабочий.

Comment: тут можно выполнять кэширование, делать подмену https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith#Examples

Comment: если понимаете английский - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox там красочно расскажут зачем всё это нужно ...

Comment: интересное чтиво, спасибо :)